# how to hide or obscure sensitive json data from dev-tools

Tags: json, security

Is there a way to *hide* or *obscure* all or part of a JSON object containing sensitive data from devtools like chrome devtools or firebug?

For example an object containing, Account Numbers, Account Balances, PINS etc.

[This post from Quora seems to says it's not possible](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-hide-JSON-data-from-tools-like-Chrome-development-tools-and-Firebug-etc-as-a-security-beyond-https)

Comment: any data that you do not want users to have you shouldnt send it to their browsers. simple as that. why would you even send peoples account numbers.

Comment: It is not possible as you say. If the computer is able to read it, no matter how, the user is also able. Just keep all sensitive data server-side. Assume anything you send to the browser can be viewed.

Comment: @JoshKisb how do you display an account number in a Mobile Banking App?

Comment: @Alejandro same question, how do you display an Account Number or an Account Balance if you do not transmit it to the client device?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu In a mobile banking app a user can be allowed to see their own account number after they have been authenticated and that data is encrypted with ssl

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu If you want to display it, why obscure or hide in the first place?

Comment: @JoshKisb for example a web-api over ssl would still have json in plain-text

Comment: @Alejandro user specific data, that a user needs to view. I don't see your argument.

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu even a web api has authentication mechanisms. if you want to display data to the user then they obviously need access to it to see it. i dont get your point

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu That's my precise question. If the user needs to view it, why try to obscure it from the user to begin with? In that case, the user doesn't even needs the developer tools to view the data, it'll be displayed in plain text to him.